# jQuery preg replacing through matches loop?

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery. What I am trying to do is take a DIV and find all instances of a timestamp, and run it through a loop. Assume that my target is:

```
var $target = $('#my-target');
```

Then I want to match the following regex: `(?!(?:[^<]+>|[^>]+</a>))\b([\d:]+)\b`.
This will match all timestamps that do not already exists within an `<a>` tag.

I then want to take the resulting timestamp string (ie: `4:45`), convert it to seconds (`285`), and then replace the timestamp text with the following:

```
<a onclick="youtubeSeek(285)">4:45</a>
```

How would I get this done with jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
var regex = /(?!(?:[^<]+>|[^>]+<\/a>))\b([\d:]+)\b/gi;
html = this.$target.html().replace(regex, function(match, stamp)
{
    var seconds = stamp.split(':').reduce((acc,time) => (60 * acc) + +time);
    return '<a href="#player" onclick="seekTo('+seconds+')">'+stamp+'</a>';
});

this.$target.html(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do parts of the job, not everything is coded.

```js
    function tsToSecond(ts) {
      // TODO
      return 123;
    }
 
    function youtubeSeek(tsInSec) {
       alert(tsInSec);
    }
 
    var $target = $('#my-target');
    // Get all your timestamps
    var timestamps = [];
    var links = $('a');
    $.each (links, function(i, a){
      if ($(a).text().match(/\d(\d)?([:,]\d\d)/g)) {
         timestamps.push(a);
      }
    });
    // Loop on each
    $.each (timestamps, function(i, tsLink) {
      var originalLink = $(tsLink);
      var ts = $(tsLink).text();
      // Convert timestampe to second
      var tsInSec = tsToSecond(ts);
      // Generate new link
      var link = $('<a></a>').attr('link-ts',tsInSec).text(ts).on('click', function(e){
        // Get tsInSec from link
        youtubeSeek($(e.target).attr('link-ts'));
      });
      originalLink.replaceWith(link);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a>1:10</a>
<a>20:45</a>
<a>12:34</a>
```

Comment: That would append the link to the div. I want to REPLACE the existing timestamp text with the link.

Comment: Also getting the error: `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: regex`

Comment: It's to give you hint...I will not do all your job

Comment: This doesn't match text. This matches existing links. I don't have existing links.